# css transition inconsistent when triggered on touch move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am triggering a css position change  (with css transition animation) when the user scrolls below a certain point.  This works fine on chrome/ safari on the pc but is inconsistent on the iphone. It sometimes jumps instead of animating, sometimes it does nothing and ocassionally animates.

I've tried using jQuery animate, added translate3d and put the element on its own layer, all of which produced the same results.

Here's the code:

```
    var logoUp = false;
    $(window)[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
      console.log($(window).scrollTop());
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 33) {
         if(!logoUp){
           $('.trig_logo').css({ 'top': '-90px' })
           logoUp = true;
         }


      } else {
           if(logoUp){
           $('.trig_logo').css({ 'top': '0px' })
           logoUp = false;
         }
      }
    })
```

CSS

```
.trig_logo {
    background:url(/img/head_foot/logo.png)  center 0px no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised `-webkit-transition` works on an iPhone at all.

Typically you'll see something like:

```
-webkit-transition: .25s top;
-moz-transition: .25s top;
-o-transition: .25s top;
transition: .25s top; /* <-- actual standard */
```

Vendor prefixes are amazing right? (**not**)

Comment: We're using safari on iphone and using `-webkit-transition` on other elements and they're animating fine fine.