# CSS transition during touchmove on iOS 7 devices won't run

Tags: jquery, ios, webkit, css-transitions

The CSS classes of an element `x` changes whenever the user scrolls up from `.stash.off` to `.stash.off.in` and from `.stash.off.in` to `.stash.off` when the user scrolls down. The CSS selectors `.stash`, `.stash.off` and `.stash.in` are defined as followed:

```
.stash
{
    position: absolute;

    visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: .35s;
            transition: .35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -60px);
            transform: translate(0, -60px);
}
.stash.in
{
    visibility: visible;

    -webkit-transition: .35s;
            transition: .35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.stash.off
{
    position: fixed;

    -webkit-transition: .35s;
            transition: .35s;
}
```

Using the `scroll` event to perform the transitions with jQuery's `toggleClass()` works flawless on desktops and touch devices. But `scroll` on touch devices is fired with `touchend` which brings some kind of delay. To get rid of this delay `touchmove` should be the replacement for `scroll` on touch devices.

But the same JS code working with `scroll` doesn't work on some touch devices when `touchmove` is used. Instead of an animation the target element `x` just pops in and out without any transition. Mostly Apple devices with iOS 7 seems to be affected.

How can I get the transition get working on such Apple devices when `touchmove` is used?

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eWEnL/). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158498/css-transition-inconsistent-when-triggered-on-touch-move) seems be related.